# I keep getting the same answer, no matter what I put in

Tags: c++

We're doing an assignment in my computer science class that requires us to find the future value of an investment after "n" number of years that the user inputs. It's written in C++. This is the code as I have it now:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int P=1000;
    int i=0.0275;
    int FV;
    int n;
    cout << "enter number of years:"<< endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "the future value is:"<< endl;
    FV = P*(1+(i*n));
    cout << FV << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

I keep ending up with an answer of 1000 no matter what "n" I input. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: `int i=0.0275;` gives `i == 0`. The compiler is likely warning you about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int P=1000;
    float i=0.0275; //float instead of int
    float FV; //FV should also be float as it will be storing decimal values
    int n;
    cout << "enter number of years:"<< endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "the future value is:"<< endl;
    FV = P*(1+(i*n));
    cout << FV << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

the mistake you have done is the type you assigned to your variables! as int only handles integer values i becomes 0 and your result becomes 1000! use float instead of int for numbers with decimal points!

Comment: It's better to use `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Datatype of i is int as a result of which your floating point value of i will be rounded of to 0 and you will end up getting the same output doesn't matter what your n value is. Change the datatype of your i and FV varaiable from int to float then your output changes based on what n value you key in